# Is there any photo editor Plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, dojo, mootools

Hi people, is there any photo editor plugin in jQuery, dojo, MooTools or HTML5? I want to make a thing like this:
http://www.buildasign.com/PowerDesign.aspx?T=6270536F632B5051594D762F785033704B4754634C773D3D&cid=1915.

Thanks.

Comment: Ali Nouman, did you manage to solve this? How do you save and output the elements in the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

In dojo there is dijit.editor: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/editor/

Comment: this site editing a banner or sign  functionality is also made in dojo i think so

Answer (score 0):

I would not call that a photo editor.  It's actually more of an HTML editor.

So, any of the various WYSIWYG editors (like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and many others) can be used to build what you posted a link to.

Comment: I don't see how ckeditor is the same as what the OP's link shows could you elaborate on how they are the same thing  ?